# WSO2 EI Iteration with Array with Inner Json Array elements in WSO2 EI 6.5.0

Tags: arrays, iterator, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am receiving `jsonpayload` as response after calling [bigQuery](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-bigquery/blob/master/docs/jobs.md) API.

**Source Table Data look like this:**

[image: table]

**JSON Payload for above Table:**

```
{
 "kind": "bigquery#queryResponse",
 "schema": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "name": "Name",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "Age",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   }
  ]
 },
 "jobReference": {
  "projectId": "testbig-235116",
  "jobId": "job_GECobzPaLdbBW-SqIG-WrfOzaqtQ",
  "location": "US"
 },
 "totalRows": "2",
 "rows": [
  {
   "f": [
    {
     "v": "John"
    },
    {
     "v": "45"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "f": [
    {
     "v": "Harry"
    },
    {
     "v": "25"
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "totalBytesProcessed": "670",
 "jobComplete": true,
 "cacheHit": false
}
```

Note: In above table structure, only 2 rows. But in runtime 'n' number of rows might came.

I need to iterate over `rows` array elements, there is inner array named `f` which contains row data for corresponding columns .

- Columns names are defined in `fields` array ie Name, Age
- Row values are defined in 'rows' array.

I am trying to fetch each row data inside `iteration` and store it into `property` which can be used for further mediation like pushing fetched to another Database.

Iterator - Code:

```
<iterate expression="json-eval($.rows[*].f)" id="BigQID">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="*********Inside" value="Iterator **********"/>
                    <property expression="json-eval($.f[0].v[0])" name="*********v[0]"/>
                    <property expression="json-eval($.f[0].v[1])" name="*********v[1]"/>
                </log>
                <!-- Step 1: Fetch each row values and store it into property -->
                <!-- Step 2: Push data to Database by feed above row data-->
            </sequence>
        </target>
</iterate>
```

**Output:**

```
[2023-03-10 18:36:12,838] []  INFO - LogMediator *********Inside = Iterator **********, *********v[0] = , *********v[1] =
```

By using expression something like `rows[0].f[0].v` we can able to fetch, But inside Iterator how can we make this array values as dynamic. How can we fetch these data in dynamic manner ?

Could anyone able to help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are Iterating over `//rows` you will have the following fragment of the payload in each iterate cycle.

```json
{
   "f": [
    {
     "v": "XXXX"
    },
    {
     "v": "YYY"
    }
   ]
}
```

So in the Iterate, I believe it's always going to be `$.f[0].v`. Also if you want to iterate just over f values you can update the Iterate JSON Path to `json-eval($.rows[*].f)` as well. So I don't see why you would need a dynamic index. Am I missing something?

**Update**

Variation 1

```
<iterate expression="json-eval($.rows[*].f)" id="1" sequential="true">
    <target>
        <sequence>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="1:::" expression="json-eval($.[0].v)"></property>
                <property name="2:::" expression="json-eval($.[1].v)"></property>   
            </log>
        </sequence>
    </target>
</iterate>
```

Variation 2

```
<iterate expression="json-eval($.rows)" id="1" sequential="true">
    <target>
        <sequence>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="1:::" expression="json-eval($.f[0].v)"></property>
                <property name="2:::" expression="json-eval($.f[1].v)"></property>   
            </log>
        </sequence>
    </target>
</iterate>
```

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Added some more info on my question, In above table structure, only 2 rows. But in runtime 'n' number of rows might came. So i want to fetch each row data during iteration. and expression="json-eval($.f[0].v[0])" not fetching any Data

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Thanks for your suggestion, Above mentioned both ways are working. No of Table Column should be predefined, if it modified (ie adding/removing one column) , then need to make changes inside iterator to fetch that element. Anyway Thank you once again

Comment: @Justin thanks for confirming. If you think the column numbers can be dynamic you can use another Iterate mediator to iterate over the columns, the same way you are iterating over rows. Hoe this helps.